# Using injection inside a @Provides method in Dagger

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger

I have a simple service:

```
public class AccountService implements IAccountService {

    @Inject
    IAccountDAO accountDAO;

}
```

This class is provided by my module:

```
@Module(library = true )
public class ServiceModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    IAccountService provideAccountStoreService(IAccountDAO accountDAO) {
        IAccountService service= new AccountService();
        //Somehow set the accountDAO inside service
        return service;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    IAccountDAO accountDAO provideAccountDAO() {
        return new AccountDAO();
    }

}
```

Is there a way to have dagger do injection on "service" after I return it and before it's injected in some other object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was easier than I thought (and actually shown as an example in the dagger homepage):

```
@Module(library = true )
public class ServiceModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    IAccountService provideAccountStoreService(AccountService service) {
        return service;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    IAccountDAO accountDAO provideAccountDAO() {
        return new AccountDAO();
    }

}
```